# iMac screen smear

Tags: imac, screen

My iMac (27-inch, Mid 2011) has this smear that appears after it has been on for a while, that disappears overnight.

[image: screen smear]

What exactly is the problem and what is the solution?

Comment: Looks like condensation inside the LCD.

Comment: Are you in a cold or humid environment? When the smear is there, carefully use a strong suction cup to lift off the glass. On 2011s and before, it’s held on via strong magnets instead of glue. If a towel can wipe down the smear and the towel is wet, then it’s probably condensation.

Comment: That worked, I just pulled it off with my fingernails

Comment: Congrats! Please don't forget to post your findings and solution as an "Answer".